# How can I assign module arguments in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl, iverilog

I have a verilog module that has a very long list of inputs and outputs that are required.

```
module mymodule(clock,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,m13,m18,m15,m16,S26,S25,S22,S27,S14,S11,S17,S10,S13,S16,S6,S12,S19,S18,S15,S7,S9,S20,S28,S23,S8,S21,S24);
```

I am trying to write a test bench for this module. Is there a smart way to supply the arguments as an array. About half of the arguments are inputs where the other half is outputs. I tried to do something like this based on my limited verilog experience.

```
reg clk = 0;
reg inputs[16:0] = 0;
wire outputs[23:0];

mymodule tc(clk, inputs, outputs);
```

I want the variable "inputs" to act as an array that will hold all the inputs, and "outputs" will also do the same.

I also want to be able to set all the inputs to random

```
inputs = $random;
```

Is there a way to do this in Verilog or do I have to initialize all the variables manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the module is defined with individual ports, each port must be connected to individually. Verilog does not provided built in way to auto connect ports.

SystemVerilog has `.*` connections, but it only works when the net/var name matches the port name. So with SystemVerilog you could connect with intermediate assignment. *(Note: all modern Verilog simulators support most, if not all, SystemVerilog features. Simply change the file extinction from `.v` to `.sv` to enable)*

```
logic clock;
logic [15:0] inputs;
wire [22:0] outputs;
wire m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,m13,m18,m15,m16;
wire S26,S25,S22,S27,S14,S11,S17,S10,S13,S16,S6,S12,S19,S18,S15,S7,S9,S20,S28,S23,S8,S21,S24;
assign {m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,m13,m18,m15,m16} = inputs;
assign outputs = {S26,S25,S22,S27,S14,S11,S17,S10,S13,S16,S6,S12,S19,S18,S15,S7,S9,S20,S28,S23,S8,S21,S24};
mymodule tc( .* );
```

For a cleaner solution, I recommend the Emacs plugin [Verilog-Mode](https://github.com/veripool/verilog-mode) ([vim wrapper exists](https://github.com/veripool/verilog-mode/blob/master/FAQ.adoc#can-i-run-verilog-mode-from-vim)). This tool was specifically created to simplify long port list connectivity and other repetitive tasks that are common to Verilog projects. For example, the below would expand to an index to index connection

```
/* mymodule AUTO_TEMPLATE (
  .m@       (inputs[\1]),
  .S@       (outputs[\1]),
); */
mymodule dut (/*AUTOINST*/);
```

The below two templates would expand with a offset except for `m18` which explicitly connects to `inputs[13]`. *(I picked `m18` because I noticed there is no `m14` and it is defined between `m13` and `m15`)*

```
/* mymodule AUTO_TEMPLATE (
  .m@       (inputs[@"(- \1 1)"]),
  .S@       (outputs[@"(- \1 6)"]),
); */
mymodule dut (
  .m18      (inputs[13]),
   /*AUTOINST*/);
```

or

```
/* mymodule AUTO_TEMPLATE (
  .m18      (inputs[13]),
  .m@       (inputs[@"(- \1 1)"]),
  .S@       (outputs[@"(- \1 6)"]),
); */
mymodule dut (/*AUTOINST*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using some sort of code generation, in regular Verilog you have to connect all the ports individually. You can do something like:

```
reg  [2:0] inp = $random;
wire [2:0] outp;

mymodule my (clk, inp[1:0], inp[2], outp[1:0], outp[2], ...);
```

to assign everything to the same vector, but still need to type all that out.

Comment: just do not name your input variable as `input`. It is a verilog *keyword*.

Comment: Okay, what about setting all the inputs to random? Do I also have to do this individually?

Comment: @ched if you use an array for the input you can fill it with a for loop: `tci tc(clk, in[0], in[1], in[2]... for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1) in[i] = $random;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `define directive to concatenate individual bits into arrays in your testbench:

```
`define inputs {m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,m13,m18,m15,m16}
`define outputs {S26,S25,S22,S27,S14,S11,S17,S10,S13,S16,S6,S12,S19,S18,S15,S7,S9,S20,S28,S23,S8,S21,S24}
```

Then, you can use $random task:

```
initial
begin

...

`inputs = $random;

...

end
```